# How to save relationship in relationship entity?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have two class first is Company :

```
@GraphId
private Long graphId;

private String id;

private String name;
```

Second class is Product :

```
@GraphId
private Long graphId;

private String id;

private String name;
```

Between those two class the relationship is company has license for and i want to create relationship entity so I can save the property in the relationship.
So i create this relationship entity class called CompanyHasLicenseFor :

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="company_has_license_for")
public class CompanyHasLicenseFor {
    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    private String id;

    @StartNode
    private Company company;

    @EndNode
    private Product product;

    private Date startDate;

    private Date endDate;

}
```

This is the code i use to create the relationship :

```
Company company = new Company("Company Test");
companyService.save(company);
Product product = new Product("Product Test");
productService.save(product);
CompanyHasLicenseFor com = new CompanyHasLicenseFor(company, product, new Date(), new Date());
companyHasLicenseForService.save(com);
```

When i try to create the dummy data using the code above the relationship between two nodes didn't created. Only the node company and product are created.
How to create/persist the relationship entity in this case ?

Thank you

**Update #1:**

I already tried to add CompanyHasLicenseFor as a relationship property in my company class :
@GraphId
    private Long graphId;

```
private String id;

private String name;

@Relationship(type="company_has_license_for")
private CompanyHasLicenseFor companylicense;
```

Yet the relationship still not created

**Update #2:**

```
@NodeEntity
public class Company {
    @GraphId
    Long graphId;
    String id;
    String name;

    @Relationship(type="company_has_license_for", direction = "UNDIRECTED")
    Set<CompanyHasLicenseFor> companylicenses;

    .....
}

@NodeEntity
public class Product {
    @GraphId
    Long graphId;
    String id;
    String name;

    @Relationship(type = "company_has_license_for", direction = "UNDIRECTED")
    Set<CompanyHasLicenseFor> companylicenses;

    ....    
}

@RelationshipEntity(type="company_has_license_for")
public class CompanyHasLicenseFor {
    @GraphId
    Long graphId;
    String id;

    @StartNode
    Company company;

    @EndNode
    Product product;

    ....
}
```

I'm using Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE and neo4j-ogm-2.1.1

This is my [Sample Code](https://github.com/daviduck123/neo4j-relationship-entity) if needed

[Screenshot of my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pje1g.png)

Comment: Are `companyService`, `productService` and `companyHasLicenseForService` are all Spring Data `Repository`s? If so it should all work. You will probably need a `@Transactional` surrounding your three save methods if you want that action to be atomic.

Comment: @digx1 Yes all of the service will call the repository function. I already put Transactional annotation above the public class declaration. But the relationship still not created in neo4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1 :**

I look at your Sample Project. The problem is, you are not define the neo4jconfig package of your relationship model. You need to define your package of `com.example.neo.relationshipModel` at **SessionFactory** like this:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    // with domain entity base package(s)
    return new SessionFactory("com.example.neo.model","com.example.neo.relationshipModel", "BOOT-INF.classes.com.example.neo.model");
}
```

**Answer 2 :**

If you don't want to change your neo4jconfig, You can change your model structure, move the **CompanyHasLicenseFor.java** to package `com.example.neo.model` like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the SDN docs :

> paths in the graph are written starting with nodes first and then
>   relationships are created between them. Therefore, you need to
>   structure your domain models so that relationship entities are
>   reachable from node entities for this to work correctly

So I guess you need to make `CompanyHasLicenseFor` an attribute of your entities.

*Update after looking at the sample code :*

**AND**

You should ensure both your entities and relationships are scanned by the OGM. In your config (session factory init), you tell OGM to scan package `com.example.neo.model` but your relationship entity lives in package `com.example.neo.relationshipModel`, so it is not picked up.

=> Move CompanyHasLicenseFor class in the scanned package or add the other  package in the session factory constructor.

Comment: hi i already tried your solution and add the codes into my question in update #1 is that what you mean? because the relationship still not created even after i add that relationship property into my class

Comment: And are is your object graph consistent before you save? i.e. do you set company.companyLicense?

Comment: @Luanne No, i didn't set company.companyLicense after i save the relationship entity. Do i need to do that?

Comment: @Luanne I just update my Question at UPDATE 2. But the result still same, no Relationship created. I attach my Screenshot too